# элемент списка в прогресс баре tqdm

Tags: python

есть список, который я перебираю в цикле и хочу, чтобы в прогресс баре отображался элемент списка:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d','h']
for i in tqdm(l, desc='ищем значение {сюда вставить элемент списка}: ') :
   #
   #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [set_description()](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#set_description).

(c) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45519268/5741205

```
tq = tqdm(l)
desc_template = 'ищем значение {}: '

for i in tq:
   tq.set_description(desc_template.format(i))
```